# Getting alert messages (hi) in sencha touch selectfiled

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha touch select field . Everything works fine . But it displays alert message "hi", whenever i try to change the value of select field. How to avoid these messages. I am new to sencha  and couldn't figure it . Any help??

here is my code:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
      var loginPage = new Ext.form.Panel({
    fullscreen:true,
    id:'loginPage',
    items : [
        {
      xtype : 'image',
      src:'images/lock.gif',
      style: 'width:40px;height:40px;margin:auto' 
        },
        {
      xtype:'fieldset',

          items: [
      {
            xtype : 'selectfield',
            label : 'username',
            id: 'uTextField',
            name: 'uTextField',
            required: true,
            options : [
                { text : 'aaa',  value : 'aaa'  },
                { text : 'bbb', value : 'bbb' },
                { text : 'ccc',  value : 'ccc'  }]
      },      

          {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label : 'userId',

            id: 'uidTextField',
            name: 'uidTextField',
            required: true,
        options : [
                { text : '1',  value : '1'  },
                { text : '2',  value : '2'  },
                { text : '3',  value : '3'  }]

          },
      {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'logInButton',
            ui: 'action',
            padding: '10px',
            text: 'Submit',
        handler : function(){
          //function goes here
        }
      }]
        }]
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for the string 'hi' in your entire file/code? This snippet you have posted does not have it.

Comment: yeah thats what.. I dont have any alert messages like that.. I dono from where it is displaying???

Comment: I think it is coming from sencha-touch.js itself . But i dono whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. It was coming from sencha-touch-all.js , getScrollables function. There was alert("hi"); .

I commented it and now it is working fine .

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!